# Angular 11 primeng ptooltip not showing the tooltip with version 11.4.5

Tags: primeng, angular11

i am using primeng ptooltip in my angular 11 application. the tooltip not appearing.

my primeng version is

"primeng": "^11.4.5",

```
<a [pTooltip]="option.label">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

My mistake. Have to import the tooltipmodule into the correct module.

import { TooltipModule } from 'primeng/tooltip';